# Converting My Error Checker To A `try-catch-else `

Tags: python, try-catch

I have some code below that is meant to check if a list of lists contains an empty string. In context, the user of my application will fill out survey questions, but if they leave one of the survey questions empty, then I want to alert them that they need to go back and fill out the survey. I need to perform this check in a bunch of different places, so I thought that a class would be a good use-case to improve the readability and portability of my program.

However, I have come to learn of try-except blocks and thought maybe it would be a better place for the essence of my code. But I am having some issues converting my simple class into a try-except block, and would like to try and implement it this way if I can. However, I think what I want to do might not be appropriate for a try-test block, so I was hoping to get some feedback.

```py
class ErrorCheck():
    def __init__(self, survey_responses):
        self.survey_responses = survey_responses
    
    def check_empty(self):
        for item in self.survey_responses:
            if '' in item:
                print('One of these is empty')


x = ErrorCheck([['abc'],[2],['apples'],['']])
x.check_empty()
```

Comment: The code here isn't handling errors though; it's trying to cause them. `try` is used to handle errors. If you want to raise an error, you use `raise`.

Answer (score 0):

The code that you're trying to implement is pretty much correct. Except for the fact that if you want to highlight an **error**, instead of just using a `print` function, use `raise Exception()` and in the parentheses insert a string, in your case 'One of these is empty'.

This will result in output like this:
`Exception: One of these is empty`

which is probably what you're looking for.

Answer (score 0):

As others already pointed out, what you want do is probably `raise` an exception, after you raise it you can catch it in a `try`...`except` block and do something about it:

```py
survey_responses = ['a','','c']

def check_empty(responses):
    for response in responses:
        if response == '':
            raise Exception('Missing Answer: One or more answers are empty')

try:
    check_empty(survey_responses)
except Exception as exc:
    print(exc)
```